# funny repeat of barcode scanner using zxing

Tags: backbone.js, routes

In continuation of the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410265/how-to-redirect-to-same-view-after-using-barcodescanner-in-phonegap...I am posting this issue...

It has something to do with routing and backbone.js....But I cannot figure out what ? Any help/pointer would be very helpful...

This is the issue:

- I start up the phonegap app.
- then the router is called to render view 1.
- from view 1 I press a button to go to view 2.
- In view 2 I press a button to start the barcode scanner.

First time the bar code scanner it exits with the alert showing the bar code number.
second time the above sequence is repeated I need to scan 2 times before the alert is triggered. And since i scan two times two times the alert is shown...

and these kind of weird repetition happens...It is as if a view recursion is happening...

I am sure it has something to do with routing and backbone...but can't figure out what...

any help appreciated... I have posted my routes and views in earlier question...

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I had a  Button  around the button to show/trigger the bar code scanner. This led to this funny behaviour...solved...

Comment: the mistake was a more basic one. After using the view one needs  to clean up the events attached properly. In order to do that in backbone I have used."undelegateEvents()" in backbone. This solves all the above issues.